# Let $P(x_1,...,x_n) = x_1$. Proof that if $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $P(A)$ is open.

Tags: general-topology

How would I proof that? My idea is the following:

Let $\bar a \in P(A)$. That implies $\exists a \in A: P(a) = \bar a$. Now, because $A$ is open $\exists \varepsilon > 0: B_\varepsilon (a) \subseteq A$. Show, that $B_\varepsilon( \bar a) \subseteq P(A)$. For that it is enough to show that $B_\varepsilon ( \bar a) \subseteq P(B_\varepsilon(a))$, because $B_\varepsilon(a) \subseteq A$. Let $\bar x \in B_\varepsilon(\bar a) \Rightarrow \exists x \in A: P(x) = \bar x$ and we have $\vert P(x) - P(a) \vert = \vert \bar x - \bar a \vert < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \bar x \in P(B_\varepsilon (a))$

Is that sufficient, or am I missing something?

Comment: No you need to show that $|x-a|<\epsilon$ to prove the claim $

Comment: So you can't take any $x$ such that $P(x) = \bar x$. You have to choose your $x$ wisely in relationship to $a$. A picture (assuming $n=2$) might help you.

Comment: @justt Thank you so much for your reply. Why do I need to show that $\vert x - a \vert < \varepsilon$? I don't understand that because I want to show that there is an open neighborhood of $\bar a$ in $P(A)$, but $x$ and $a$ are in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: You claimed yourself that you want to show that $\bar x \in P(B_\epsilon(A))$. It means that $\bar x$ is the image of an $x$ which is in $B_\epsilon(A)$, which exactly means that $|x-a|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. As you stated, to prove $P(A)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, we need to show that given $P(a)=\bar{a}\in P(A)$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(\bar{a})\subset P(A)$. We will find such an $\epsilon>0$ after stating what we are given.

(As commented what you miss is that the implication $\bar{x}\in B_\epsilon(\bar{a})\implies\exists x\in A:P(x)=\bar{x}$ must be proven since it is same as saying $B_\epsilon(\bar{a})\subset P(A)$ which is indeed what we want to prove.)

Assume $a=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ then what we are given is the following: $\exists\epsilon_1>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon_1}(a)\in A$ since $A$ is open:
\begin{align}
B_{\epsilon_1}(a)&=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|d(x,a)<\epsilon_1\}\\
&=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|\sqrt{(x_1-a_1)^2+...+(x_n-a_n)^2}<\epsilon_1\}\\
&\implies (\bar{x},a_2,...,a_n)\in B_{\epsilon_1}(a)\quad \forall \bar{x}\in B_{\epsilon_1}(a_1).
\end{align}
where $a_1=\bar{a}$ by definition of $P$. Now choosing any $0<\epsilon\leq\epsilon_1$ what you said is proven, that is, given $\bar{x}\in B_\epsilon(\bar{a})$ we have $(\bar{x},a_2,...,a_n)\in B_{\epsilon_1}(a)\subset A$ such that $P(\bar{x},a_2,...,a_n)=\bar{x}\in P(A)$. Hence, we conclude that $B_\epsilon(\bar{a})\subset P(A)$.